# Convert SQL query with multiple GroupBy columns to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, group-by

```
SELECT 
  [TimeStampDate]
  ,[User]
  ,count(*) as [Usage]
FROM [EFDP_Dev].[Admin].[AuditLog]
WHERE [target] = '995fc819-954a-49af-b056-387e11a8875d'
GROUP BY [Target], [User] ,[TimeStampDate]
ORDER BY [Target]
```

My database table has the columns User, TimeStampDate, and Target (which is a GUID).

I want to retrieve all items for each date for each user and display count of entries.

The above SQL query works. How can I convert it into LINQ to SQL? Am using EF 6.1 and my entity class in C# has all the above columns.

Create Filter basically returns an `IQueryable` of the entire AuditLogSet :

```
using (var filter = auditLogRepository.CreateFilter())
{
  var query = filter.All
    .Where(it => it.Target == '995fc819-954a-49af-b056-387e11a8875d')
    .GroupBy(i => i.Target, i => i.User, i => i.TimeStamp);
  audits = query.ToList();
}
```

Am not being allowed to group by on 3 columns in LINQ and I am also not sure how to select like the above SQL query with count. Fairly new to LINQ.

Comment: http://www.codeducky.org/sql-queries-in-linq/ may help.

Comment: [kudvenkat](https://www.youtube.com/user/kudvenkat/playlists) LINQ Tutorial

Comment: As discussed below, because you are already filtering the results down to a single target, specifying target in the groupby and ordering based on it is useless.  You should also consider not forcing the audits into a list, but letting them remain an IQueryable and/or IEnumerable as long as possible.  Doing so would allow possible further processing (or shifting further processing to the database server) and allow the records to be processed as they are retrieved which increases throughput, lowers memory usage, and lowers garbage collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the group by columns in an `anonymous type` like this:-

```
var query = filter.All
                  .Where(it => it.Target == '995fc819-954a-49af-b056-387e11a8875d')
                  .GroupBy(x => new { x.User, x.TimeStampDate })
                  .Select(x => new 
                         {
                             TimeStampDate= x.Key.TimeStampDate,
                             User = x.Key.User,
                             Usage = x.Count()
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Grouping, ordering and selecting Target isn't necessary.

Comment: @RobertMcKee - Agree, because we are already filtering the target. Corrected, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Many people find query syntax simpler and easier to read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) (this might not be the case, I don't know), here's the query syntax version anyway.

```
var res=(from it in filter.All
    where it.Target=="995fc819-954a-49af-b056-387e11a8875d"
    group it by new {it.Target, it.User, it.TimeStampDate} into g
    orderby g.Key.Target
    select new 
               {
                TimeStampDate= g.Key.TimeStampDate,
                User=g.Key.User,
                Usage=g.Count()
               });
```

EDIT: By the way you don't need to group by Target neither OrderBy, since is already filtered, I'm leaving the exact translation of the query though.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, query syntax requires either a `select` or a `group by`.  But it looks better if you don't mix query and method syntax.

Comment: Query syntax is almost never easier to read, especially in larger queries.  You also missed that you don't need to use `it.Target` as a grouping element since it is filtered to a specific Target already, and you selected Target instead of TimeStamp.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I've found that most people would disagree that query syntax is harder to read.  That's completely an opinion and not a reason to down vote.  The wrong select is the only valid reason since the extra grouping doesn't hurt.  And you forgot that there's no point in ordering by `Target`.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Look, I just remembered what I read on that msdn link, about "it.Target", I guess you're right, still, I'm just translating the OP query, I'll add a clarification.

Comment: Since you've changed your answer to state that many people find, and corrected the select, I've removed the downvote.  IMHO, Cetin Basoz's answer looks much simpler to me than the query syntax version though.

Comment: OrderBy again, isn't needed since they will by default be ordered since he is limiting the query to one target.

Comment: I would think, query syntax or method syntax. is more readable is just a personal preference. IMHO there are cases (like using let) where you can't use method syntax and it is easier to do SelectMany with query syntax. Other than that personally I find method syntax to be easier (especially with GroupBy). Anyway I upvoted all the answers, thinking they are all right.

Comment: Yeah, "Let" is easier to write in query syntax

Comment: I can't say why everyone else prefers method syntax, but I prefer it because it is closest to what the compiler actually does.  Query syntax is compiled into method syntax behind the scenes.  Method chaining is also very common in many environments like gulp, jquery, etc, so it is more familiar than the sort-of-SQL like query syntax which is just enough different that you have to remember it isn't SQL.

Comment: I usually write method syntax, except whan I have to use Let

Comment: Sorry, I didn't take offense to your opinion, you are more than welcome to have it, even a different one, so long as you state that it is an opinion.  I view the answers as being (or should be) authoritative on the addressed subject, and opinions stated as fact is always wrong in my eyes.  The rest of your answer was excellent, and would have gotten the original poster the answer he needed, but the answer (hopefully) will also help others as well.

Comment: answer is correct except for group by group it by new {it.Target, it.User, it.TimeStampDate}  instead of TimeStamp

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan Well, the SQL query says TimeStampDate, but the OP Linq attempt says TimeStamp.

Comment: but if you group by TimeStamp , u cannot select TimeStampDate.thats the error

Answer (score 2):

To use GroupBy you need to create an anonymous object like this:

```
filter.All
      .Where(it => it.Target == '995fc819-954a-49af-b056-387e11a8875d')
      .GroupBy(i => new { i.Target, i.User, i.TimeStamp });
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unnecessary to group by target in your original SQL.

```
filter.All.Where( d => d.Target == "995fc819-954a-49af-b056-387e11a8875d")
  .GroupBy(d => new {d.User ,d.TimeStampDate} )
  .Select(d => new {
    User = d.Key.User,
    TimeStampDate = d.Key.TimeStampDate,
    Usage = d.Count()
  } );
```

Comment: this for some reason doesnt seem to compile ? is there somnething missing ? i get "the type arguments could not be inferred ) and it doesnt recognize the d object in the group by bracket

Comment: My bad, forgot to write d => in GroupBy. Edited.

Comment: thank you. I figured it out through a combination of yours and Rahuls answer . Thanks to you both . Confused whose answer i should accept. +15.